# python pandas function object has no attribute min

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to find recency but getting error

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'min'

Code:

```
#Generating recency function

# Filtering data for customerid and invoice_date
recency  = order_wise[['CustomerID','InvoiceDate']]

# Finding max data
maximum = max(recency.InvoiceDate)

# Adding one more day to the max data, so that the max date will have 1 as the difference and not zero.
maximum = maximum + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
recency['diff'] = maximum - recency.InvoiceDate
recency.head()

df = pd.DataFrame(recency.groupby('CustomerID').diff.min())
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ["CustomerID", "Recency"]
df.head()
```

Comment: You need to call the `diff` method by adding parenthesis: `recency.groupby('CustomerID').diff().min()`

Comment: diff is not a method but a column in recency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pandas DataFrame has a `diff` method.  To access the column named `'diff'` you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(recency.groupby('CustomerID')['diff'].min())
```

Or if you want to stick with dot notation, you can give the column a different name:

```
recency['Diff'] = maximum - recency.InvoiceDate

df = pd.DataFrame(recency.groupby('CustomerID').Diff.min())
```